# keep calling a function until a criteria is hit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

writing a simple blackjack game

I want it to be semi automated.

I have this function after the player hits stick

```
  stick = () => {
    while(this.dealersTotal() < 21){
      setInterval(this.dealToDealer, 3000)
    }
  }
```

however, when I do this it just freezes as I think im exceeding the stack. any ideas why this would do this? I can post more code but not sure seeing the other functions will help too much

dealersTotal is just a function that returns a number
dealToDealer just sets the state of dealers hand with the next card and then removes the top card from the deck

Comment: if you do need an delay, I'd use setTimeout rather than interval

Comment: `setInterval` doesn't block, so what this does is create an assumedly infinite number of calls to `this.dealToDealer` that each happen 3 seconds after the last (and repeat independently).  This will blow up your memory very quickly!

Comment: `while(this.dealersTotal() < 21)`  so if this is less than 21, you will get an infinite loop, as it will never change.  You maybe just want an `if` check, followed by a `setTimeout`, not setInterval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop that is creating new intervals (which will run indefinitely each) on each iteration. That's what's killing your app.

The simplest solution would be (https://jsfiddle.net/29L556s9/10/):

```
stick = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(dealersTotal() < 21) {
      dealToDealer();
      stick();
    }
  }, 3000);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `setInterval` will be executed recurrently unless you stop it with the function `clearInterval`.

**Use the setTimeout instead:**

```
stick = () => {
   while(this.dealersTotal() < 21){
      setTimeout(this.dealToDealer, 3000);
   }
}
```

**Important:** If `this.dealersTotal()` always returns a number less than `21` your code will enter in an infinite loop.

Comment: That's won't fix the problem though!! :(  you will still get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

While loop can sick your perfomance, try to play around with using only interval.
Example:

```
  stick = () => {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
   if(this.dealersTotal() < 21) {
    this.dealersTotal();
    clearInterval(this.interval)
   }
  }, 3000);
 }
```

Comment: ok interesting. this only did one more though. so when the total got to 7, it didnt call it again?

Comment: also I think you meant to call `this.dealToDealer` on line 4

Answer (score 0):

`Let interval = setInterval(()=>{

//Do what you want here

If(this.dealersTotal() >= 21){ clearInterval(interval) } // keep interval loop running until dealersTotal is bigger than or equal to 21
},50)//50ms`

With your current one, you are calling while loop and this loop will create a new setInterval so if you have 10 while loop, setInterval will be called 10 times which will create infinite interval which eventually exceeds processing power. So the best is to keep interval only as while loop will block. While loop is good for definite value or until something happens such as a keyboard press. But when you want a UI multiple things happening then setInterval is the better option.